# How to add comment on snippet view of wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

i am studying wagtail recently,i have a  question,please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5gGo.png)

i tried reading doc and searching example from stackoverflow,but nothing found,so i would like rasie the question here for help.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Snippets do not currently support comments. Have a look at the [supported options](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v5.2.2/topics/snippets/features.html). Perhaps you could use a Workflow to get what you are looking for.

Comment: really thanks for reply.  i am not sure how to make workflow works like add comment, could you suggest ?

Comment: and is there a plan to support such feature in future ?

Comment: What I was thinking is that the default moderation workflow provides a comment field. Search for "TaskStateCommentForm" on https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_tasks.htm You will probably also want to read the user documentation on customizing workflows https://guide.wagtail.org/en-latest/how-to-guides/configure-workflows-for-moderation/